# VPC Link Throwing Error on Creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-vpc

I am having trouble creating a VPC Link in AWS services. I have my NLB ready and active. However when I create the VPC Link in AWS API Gateway I get an error. I tried creating it via awscli but no error appears until late processing. Is there any clue where I can check a missing configuration? Could it be a temporary issue with Amazon servers?

[VPC Links Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlGpq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. My NLB targets were unhealthy. VPC link won't tell you until late created.